# How to maintain changes on multiple files on a branch and not getting the changes of an another?

Tags: git

I an trying to use gitignore to do the tasks:

- I need to some files to maintain the changes from a master branch when cloned or checkout from.
- When mergin a child branch on this master branch, the changes on this files or folders should not come to master branch
- The changes ignored by master branch must be avaiable for branches that checkout from other branches checkout from these branches that are childs from master.

##### This is an image that should explain better what I am trying to do:

[An Diagramn of what I am trying to attain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIX7H.png)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You want to ignore some file changes when merging into master, is that it? And you would like this process to be automatic?

Comment: Yeah, and still maintain the changes already done in the master, already read something using removal of cached and --assume-unchanged, but I can't workout how to use this in way that seens secure and automatic

Comment: You *cannot* use `.gitignore` files this way; they don't do that *at all*. There are some rather ugly tricks that *can* be used, but they *should not be used*. See [this GIT FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F).

Comment: The git model doesn't support anything like this, out of box.  Git manages directory trees, and doesn't have any facility for maintaining mandatory differences over time.  You could, I suppose, build your own tools on top of git for this (git hooks perhaps).